# How does Apache Beam's CombineValues operate over elements when executing arithmetic operations

Tags: python, apache-beam

This is a bit of a contrived example, but I have been exploring the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combinevalues/) for `CombineValues` and wish understand what I'm seeing.

If I combine values and perform some arithmetic operations on the values (the goal is to calculate percentages of keys present in a bounded stream), then I need to use the `AverageFn` (as defined in *Example 8* in [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combinevalues/) and provided in the source code example snippets).

However, this (based on *Example 5*) does not work:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:

  counts = ( pipeline
             | 'create' >>  beam.Create(['xxx'])
             | 'key it' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem, 1))
             | 'combine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(
                 lambda values: sum(values)/2
                 )
             | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
           )
```

as it produces

```
('xxx', 0.25)
```

I ultimately wanted to compute the count via

```
  totals = pipeline | 'Count elements' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
```

and then use the singleton approach they suggest (where I provide
`beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(totals)` to `beam.CombineValues`).

My question is, why does CombineValues appear to execute twice (probably going to be some facepalming)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the combiner is being called twice is because of the MapReduce phases. Since the function you are using (halving the mean) is not associative, you'd need a an "advance combiner" as in the *example 8* you mention.

What is happening in your current code is, from `(xxx, 1)` calculate the half mean `(xxx, 0.5)` and then, when merging the values, it halves it again, making `(xxx, 0.25)`.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235815/why-is-the-combine-function-called-three-times/63244664#63244664) I explain a similar concept.

For your particular case, as mentioned, you need "advance combiners"

```
 with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:

    def combiner(elements):
        print(elements)
        return sum(elements)/2

    class HalfMean(beam.CombineFn):
        def create_accumulator(self):
            # Tuple of sum, count
            return (0, 0)

        def add_input(self, accumulator, input):
            # Add the current element to sum, add one to count
            new_tuple = (accumulator[0] + input, accumulator[1] + 1)
            return new_tuple

        def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
            # Join all accumulators
            partial_sums = [x[0] for x in accumulators]
            partial_counts = [x[1] for x in accumulators]
            merged_tuple = (sum(partial_sums), sum(partial_counts))
            return merged_tuple

        def extract_output(self, sum_count_tuple):
            # Now we can output half of the mean
            mean = sum_count_tuple[0]/sum_count_tuple[1]
            return mean/2

    counts = ( pipeline
             | 'create' >> beam.Create(['xxx'])
             | 'key it' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem, 1))
             #| 'combine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(combiner)
             | 'advance combine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(HalfMean())
             | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
           )
```

I'm leaving your old combiner with a print so you see what's happening.

Anyhow, that is still not a `CombineValues` but a `CombinerPerKey`. `CombineValues` takes a key value pair on which the value is an iterator, and applies the combiner to it. In the following case, the elements that it's taking are `('a', [1, 2, 3])` and `('b', [10])`. Here you have the example

```
    kvs = [('a', 1),
           ('a', 2),
           ('a', 3),
           ('b', 10),
   ]

    combine_values = (pipeline
             | 'create_kvs' >> beam.Create(kvs)
             | 'gbk' >> beam.GroupByKey()
             | 'combine values' >> beam.CombineValues(HalfMean())
             | 'print cv' >> beam.Map(print)
           )
```