# How to calculate percentage change in Apache Beam? i.e. pandas.DataFrame.pct_change

Tags: pandas, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

I am new to Apache Beam, been stuck on this seemingly very simple thing for a few hours:

How do I accomplish **pandas.DataFrame.pct_change** in Apache Beam?

I am reading my data from CSV (using **beam.io.ReadFromText**), say:

```
0    90 
1    91 
2    85
```

I want to turn it into percentage change between the rows, i.e.

```
0         NaN
1    0.011111
2   -0.065934
```

How does one do this in **Apache Beam** pipeline?

All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage of Beam over Pandas is the ability to parallelise a lot the operations. The parallelism also happens in the read, so there's no a simple concept of "next" as in Pandas.

This is the main reason why operations that require a fixed order (for example, all the rolling features from Pandas) are harder to do in Beam (and other parallel ETL frameworks). They would pretty much require to send all elements to the same worker and perform the operation there, so you are losing the advantage of Beam and probably be better off with Pandas.

**BUT**, since you have a `row` field that tell us the order, we can do a workaround using the `row` field as `timestamps` and `SlidingWindows` without losing the parallelism.

Since the Combiner (the way we group things) is not commutative/associative, we need and advanced combiner. There's more info about this concept in these two answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800692/how-does-apache-beams-combinevalues-operate-over-elements-when-executing-arithm/63811114#63811114) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235815/why-is-the-combine-function-called-three-times/63244664#63244664)

```
p = beam.Pipeline()

class RollingChange(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return []

    def add_input(self, list, input):
        list.append(input)
        return list

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        final_list = []
        for list in accumulators:
            final_list += list
        return final_list

    def extract_output(self, list_of_list):
        if len(list_of_list) == 2:
            first = list_of_list[0]
            second = list_of_list[1]
            second["change"] = second["value"] / first["value"] - 1
            return second
        elif len(list_of_list) == 1 and list_of_list[0]['row'] == 0:
            list_of_list[0]["change"] = 0
            return list_of_list[0]
        else:
            pass

elements = [
    {"row": 0, "value": 90},
    {"row": 1, "value": 91},
    {"row": 2, "value": 85},
    {"row": 3, "value": 100},
    {"row": 4, "value": 200}
]

(p | Create(elements)
 | Map(lambda x: window.TimestampedValue(x, x['row'])) # adds row as timestamp for windows
 | WindowInto(window.SlidingWindows(2, 1))
 | beam.core.CombineGlobally(RollingChange()).without_defaults()
 | beam.core.Filter(lambda x: x != None) # filters the last row (4)
 | Map(print))

p.run()
```

Output of this is (note the order may change)

```
{'row': 1, 'value': 91, 'change': 0.011111111111111072}
{'row': 0, 'value': 90, 'change': 0}
{'row': 2, 'value': 85, 'change': -0.06593406593406592}
{'row': 3, 'value': 100, 'change': 0.17647058823529416}
{'row': 4, 'value': 200, 'change': 1.0}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I do have to admit that I find Beam very wordy, vs spark. A lot less intuitive, and more lines to write